# Forward all param from xsl:template to another

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to forward all param received in a template to another without knowing them ?

Example :

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="bar">
        <xsl:with-param name="father-id" select="@id"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" priority="9">
    <!-- do some things -->
    <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar">
    <xsl:param name="father-id"/>
    <!-- do some things with my param -->
</xsl:template>
```

Here my param `father-id` is lost because of my `xsl:template match="*"`.

So, is there a way to forward it at the `<xsl:next-match />` step but not using the following code because there can be more cases than this one and with different params ?

```
<xsl:template match="*" priority="9">
    <xsl:param name="father-id"/>
    <!-- do some things -->
    <xsl:next-match>
        <xsl:with-param name="father-id" select="{father-id}"/>
    </xsl:next-match>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you in advance.

Gerald.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="bar">
        <xsl:with-param name="father-id" select="@id" tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" priority="9">
    <!-- do some things -->
    <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar">
    <xsl:param name="father-id" tunnel="yes"/>
    <!-- do some things with my param -->
</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 2.0** only - but then so is `xsl:next-match`.
http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#tunnel-params